# How to reset Android Webview HTTPS connection

Tags: android, https, webview

I have an Android 4.2 app with an embedded WebView.
  The WebView loads an HTTPS page at startup and reloads it periodically.

Everything works fine for a couple hours, then I start getting SSL errors when loading the page (Chromium error: SSL handshake failed). At this point, the page will not load anymore.
  What is odd is that I have another running task that checks availability of the server using a HttpUrlConnection which always works.

I suspect the WebView is caching something but could not figure out what.
  I tried the following with no effects:

```
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();  
webView.clearSslPreferences();  
CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webView.getContext());
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

Does anyone know how to properly reset a WebView ?

Regards,
  Etienne

Comment: You could trying removing your WebView from your parent layout and creating a new one with constructor / layout inflater and then adding that one to your parent. Seems a bit janky, but may help you get around this issue if your requirement is to show this webview for extended periods of time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented this but it does not seem to work as I get the same errors. Maybe there is a WebView connections manager that's proccess-wide ?

Comment: Hey Etienne, I have the same problem. Did u get the solution. Please let me know. This problem is solved, by Force Stop the application from App setting. Temporarily , what I have done is , in onDestroy() method of the activity, if the SSL Handshake error is observed, I call the android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: Hi, I basically settled for the same thing, which I don't really consider as a solution! But no workaround seemed to work.